# Pandas: expanding_apply with groupby for unique counts of string type

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
id = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]
color = ['red','blue','red','black','blue','red','black','black']
test = pd.DataFrame(zip(id, color), columns = ['id', 'color'])
```

and would like to create a column of the running count of the unique colors grouped by id so that the final dataframe looks like this:

```
   id  color  expanding_unique_count
0   0    red                       1
1   0   blue                       2
2   0    red                       2
3   0  black                       3
4   1   blue                       1
5   1    red                       2
6   1  black                       3
7   1  black                       3
```

I tried this simple way:

```
def len_unique(x):
    return(len(np.unique(x)))

test['expanding_unique_count'] = test.groupby('id')['color'].apply(lambda x: pd.expanding_apply(x, len_unique))
```

And got ValueError: could not convert string to float: black

If I change the colors to integers:

```
color = [1,2,1,3,2,1,3,3]

test = pd.DataFrame(zip(id, color), columns = ['id', 'color'])
```

Then running the same code above produces the desired result. Is there a way for this to work while maintaining the string type for the column color?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `expanding_apply` and `rolling_apply` mainly work on numeric values. Maybe try creating a numeric column to code the color string as numeric values (this can be done by make color column categorical), and then `expanding_apply`.

```
# processing
# ===================================
# create numeric label
test['numeric_label'] = pd.Categorical(test['color']).codes
# output: array([2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0], dtype=int8)

# your expanding function
test['expanding_unique_count'] = test.groupby('id')['numeric_label'].apply(lambda x: pd.expanding_apply(x, len_unique))
# drop the auxiliary column
test.drop('numeric_label', axis=1)

   id  color  expanding_unique_count
0   0    red                       1
1   0   blue                       2
2   0    red                       2
3   0  black                       3
4   1   blue                       1
5   1    red                       2
6   1  black                       3
7   1  black                       3
```

### Edit:

```
def func(group):
    return pd.Series(1, index=group.groupby('color').head(1).index).reindex(group.index).fillna(0).cumsum()

test['expanding_unique_count'] =  test.groupby('id', group_keys=False).apply(func)
print(test)

   id  color  expanding_unique_count
0   0    red                       1
1   0   blue                       2
2   0    red                       2
3   0  black                       3
4   1   blue                       1
5   1    red                       2
6   1  black                       3
7   1  black                       3
```

Comment: @rebka You can also define your own apply function to achieve the goal by using the `cumsum` trick. See the edited part.

Comment: Thanks again, @Jianxun Li